# creating dict of dicts in python with itertools?

Tags: python, dictionary, python-itertools

I am generating many random points within [0,1]x[0,1]  that is, many points within the unit square.  I need to be able to find all points in subregions of the form [0.3,0.4]x[0.5,0.6] (or similar)

Currently my plan is to initialize a dict of dicts by the following:

```
group = {}
for xctr in range(10):
    group[xctr] = {yctr:[] for yctr in range(10)}
```

and then simply put each point into the appropriate list.

Is there a faster/better way using itertools (if not, using some other method?)  Basically it looks like itertools.product gets me partway there, but it's not clean.

Comment: Are we speaking about 10×10 raster only?

Comment: @dlask Initially yes, but as I generalize this approach, I expect it to become much larger.